# Bluemix Monitoring and Analytics: Resource Monitoring - JsonSender request error

Tags: analytics, monitoring, ibm-cloud, log-analysis

I am having problems with the Bluemix Monitoring and Analytics service.
I have 2 applications with bindings to a single Monitoring and Analytics service. Every ~1 minute I get the following log line in both apps:

> ERR [Resource Monitoring][ERROR]:  JsonSender request error: Error: unsupported certificate purpose

When I remove the bindings, the log message does not appear. I also greped my code for anything related to "JsonSender" or "Resource Monitoring" and did not find anything.

I am doing some major refactoring work on our server, which might have broken things. However, our code does not use the Monitoring service directly (we don't have a package that connects to the monitoring server or something like that) - so I will be very surprised if the problem is due to the refactoring changes. I did not check the logs before doing the changes.

Any ideas will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluemix have 3 production environments: ng, eu-gb, au-syd, and I tested with ng, and eu-gb, both using 2 applications with same M&A service, and tested with multiple instances. They are all work fine.

Meanwhile, I received a similar problem that claim they are using Node.js 4.2.6.

So there are some more information we need to know to identify the problem: 
1. Which version of Node.js are you using (Bluemix Default or any other one)
2. Which production environment are you using? (ng, eu-gb, au-syd)
3. Is there any environment variables are you using in your application?
   (either the creating in code one, or the one using USER-DEFINED Variables)
4. One more thing, could you please try to delete the M&A service, and create it again, in case we are trapped in a previous fault of M&A.

`cf ds <your M&A service name>
cf cs MonitoringAndAnalytics <plan> <your M&A service name>`

Comment: My `package.json` contains `"engines":{"node":"4.2.*"}`. We are running in US South. The stack is `cflinuxfs2`. We have plenty of environment variables for our own use. The only one that might create a collision is NODE_ENV that is set to "development". I have tried removing the M&A service and creating a new one from the Bluemix dashboard.

Comment: I tried with Node.js v4.2.* as you did, yes, the problem occur. Then the problem is about the http/https module difference between v0.10 / v0.12 and v4.2. We will fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: Please let us know when the problem is solved. Will changing my engine to node 5.* help? Does Bluemix currently support node 5?

Comment: Hi Yue, I will be happy to contact you in private and follow what's going on with this problem. While I am getting these error messages, the monitoring service does not work at all.

Comment: It seems like the problem doesn't happen anymore. Did you fix it on your side or is it just a matter of probability?

Comment: Hello, This problem should be fixed in M&A side. About Node 5.* support, I think Node 5.* is not a stable version, so we didn't support it officially yet.

Comment: There seems a regression on this problem, we will fix that as soon as possible.

Comment: We are also seeing the same problem in an environment with Node 4.2.* (4.2.6)

Comment: Try setting the engine to "4.2.4" (in package.json -> engines -> node) instead of "4.2.*". Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS versions 4.4.* all appear to work
NodeJS uses openssl and apparently did/does not like how one of the M&A server certificates were constructed.
Unfortunately NodeJS does not expose the openssl verify purpose API.
Please consider upgrading to 4.4 while we consider how to change the server's certificates in the least disruptive manner as there are other application types that do not have an issue with them (e.g. Liberty and Ruby)

Answer (score 0):

setting node js version 4.2.4 in package.json worked for me, however this is an alternative by-passing solution. Actual fix is being handled by core team. Thanks.